# TFS 2017 Builds

Tags: tfs, build

We have migrated to TFS 2017 from TFS 2010.

While executing the builds, the builds are taking too long to get completed successfully.

Previously, in 2010, we use to use community build manager to execute the builds, in TFS 2017 do we have any such tools to queued up the builds to execute them all at once. Not just manually executing them one by one.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio did you install on the build agent machine? Does it have the same issue when building the project with the local Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi Andy Li-MSFT,  yes we are using earlier version in build agent server

Comment: Do you mean that you are using the earlier version of Visual Studio 2017? If it is, then you can try the solutions mentioned in below answer.

Comment: yeah our build agent servers are using old versions of VS 2017

Comment: One more question, please let me know if any solutions. We have many build definitions somewhat 40. So to execute them one by one it takes lots of time. Is there any way by which I can trigger them simultaneously in one click some script or tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many reasons for this problem, eg hardware, software, bandwidth, size of the project... Please refer to below article to check that, it's still available for vNext build (Task based build process): [Optimizing Team Foundation Server Build Time](https://wouterdekort.com/2014/10/07/optimizing-team-foundation-server-build-time/)

In case if you installed earlier version of Visual Studio 2017 on your build agent machine, then you may have this problem. There are issues tracked in developer community site :

- [VS 2017 Build very slow](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/37643/vs-2017-build-very-slow.html)
- [Slow compile times compared with VS 2013](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/83893/slow-compile-times-compared-with-vs-2013.html?childToView=111849#comment-111849)

In this case, you can try the solutions/workarounds mentioned in the issues, alternatively you can also try to install VS 2015 for the building.